# sum of double variables

Tags: c++, sum, double

I have problem tyring to do some basic addition. I don't understand why the returned value for J11 is 0 while A11*G11 and A12*G21 have finite values. I know it has to do with variable types - most likely. Your help is much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

void simple() 
{
double G11,G12,G13,G21,G22,G23,G31,G32;
double G33,G41,G42,G43,G51,G52,G53,G61;
double G62,G63,G71,G72,G73,G81,G82,G83;
double J11;
double xx,yy,zz;
double A11,A12;
vector<double> xcoor;
vector<double> ycoor;
vector<double> zcoor;
double G1=1/sqrt(3);
double G2=-1/sqrt(3);

    xcoor.push_back(G1);
    xcoor.push_back(G2);
    xcoor.push_back(G1);
    xcoor.push_back(G2);
    xcoor.push_back(G1);
    xcoor.push_back(G2);
    xcoor.push_back(G1);
    xcoor.push_back(G2);

    ycoor.push_back(G1);
    ycoor.push_back(G2);
    ycoor.push_back(G2);
    ycoor.push_back(G1);
    ycoor.push_back(G1);
    ycoor.push_back(G2);
    ycoor.push_back(G2);
    ycoor.push_back(G1);

    zcoor.push_back(G2);
    zcoor.push_back(G2);
    zcoor.push_back(G2);
    zcoor.push_back(G2);
    zcoor.push_back(G1);
    zcoor.push_back(G1);
    zcoor.push_back(G1);
    zcoor.push_back(G1);


    for (size_t z = 0 ; z < 43 ; z++) {
        for (size_t y = 0 ; y < 43 ; y++) {
            for (size_t x = 0 ; x < 43 ; x++) {                         

                G11=x;
                G12=y;
                G13=z;
                G21=x;
                G22=y+1.;
                G23=z;
                G31=x+1.;
                G32=y+1.;
                G33=z;
                G41=x+1.;
                G42=y;
                G43=z;
                G51=x;
                G52=y;
                G53=z+1.;
                G61=x;
                G62=y+1.;
                G63=z+1.;
                G71=x+1.;
                G72=y+1.;
                G73=z+1.;
                G81=x+1.;
                G82=y;
                G83=z+1.;

            for(size_t t = 0 ; t < 8 ; t++){

                 xx = xcoor[t];
                 yy = ycoor[t];
                 zz = zcoor[t];

                A11=(-1./8.)*(1-yy)*(1-zz);         
                A12=(1./8.)*(1-yy)*(1-zz);

                J11 = A11 * G11 + A12 * G21;

                cout<<J11<<endl;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}



int main ()
{

    simple();
    cout << "Computation done." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I see a declaration with that many variables I think to myself, why is this person not using an array/vector? PS: Tag this as C++

Comment: I am sort of new to this and don't feel comfortable yet with array/vector.

Comment: Be an angel and isolate the problem down to a single statement. The answer will then be obvious to us old cats.

Comment: You will never feel comfortable with either if you never try to use them

Comment: Once you use them, you won't feel comfortable declaring so many variables/.

Comment: variable J11 should be none zero but the code returns zero. If i cout<<A11*G11<<endl; or cout<<A12*G21<<endl; then i can see the actual values of the two terms but the sum of them some how returns 0. Does that help?

Comment: You have a ton of variables there, none of them is named JJ

Comment: @user147813 If you need help reducing your code read this: [mcve]

Comment: For your own debugging purposes. Try placing cout statements at various points of your computation to see if your values are what you'd expect at that stage. Or if you feel comfortable with your development environment, place break points and step through the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to be zero:

```
J11 = A11 * G11 + A12 * G21;
```

because A11 = -A12 as you can see here:

```
A11=(-1./8.)*(1-yy)*(1-zz);         
A12=(1./8.)*(1-yy)*(1-zz);
```

and G11 = G21 because of:

```
G11 = x
G21 = x
```

Nevertheless I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: Thank you all. I had made some very basic mistake in my code because of the number of variables. Just as a closure, please let me know if you know of any good sources and examples to work with arrays/vectors.